# How to dynamically rewrite Jetty's URL handling rule?

Tags: servlets, web-applications, jetty, servlet-filters

I have an existing Jetty web app project where the webapps folder is set up like this:

```
webapps
   |
   | root
       |
       | icons
           |
           | a.jpg
```

and I can access `a.jpg` by accessing this URL:

```
http://localhost/icons/a.jpg
```

I guess that's the default root folder in Jetty where it can serve static contents? Since I can't find any reference to the "root" folder in any configuration file.

I would like to dynamically change the location of this "root" folder so that I can, say, do this (pseudocode)

```
setRoot("C:/myNewRoot/icons")
```

and when I go to `http://localhost/icons/a.jpg`, it would serve `C:/myNewRoot/icons/a.jpg` instead of `webapps/root/icons/a.jpg`

I'm guessing this will involve some sort of `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` that would handle `/icons/*`, but I can't figure out how.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the base resource of a WebApp / War file, without breaking everything else that the WebApp depends on.

As for the meaning of "root" and "ROOT" as a deployable name ...

- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/automatic-webapp-deployment.html
- https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-contexts.html#usng-the-context-provider

Comment: If I don't need to change the whole `root` folder, just the `icons` location and the URL handling, is it possible? I.e. by default visiting `http://localhost/icons/*` would serve static files out of `webapps/root/icons`, but is it possible to dynamically change that URL to serve icons from somewhere else instead?